# Add multiple numbers taken from user input and append it to a list

Tags: python, list, append

I just have this little program here that I want to use to take an input from a user (as if entering a password). I have a list with the password in it, I then take the users input and place it in an empty class. Then compare that class to the one with the password in it, if it matches it will return "good". However I've only been able to do this using one digit. How would allow for the user to use multiple integers? And is this an efficient way of doing this sort of thing? Is there are quicker more efficient method? Thanks.

```
class KeyCode(object):


    def access(self):
        room_code = [1]
        print "Before you enter you must provide the room code: "
        attempt = []
        code = int(raw_input('>>'))
        attempt.append(code)
        if attempt == room_code:
             print "Good"
        else: 
             return 'death'

class Boxing_room(KeyCode):


    def enter(self): 
        print "This is the boxing studio"

        return 'Gymnast_room'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists aren't necessarily needed. You can just compare strings, or if your code is only numbers, integers.

Also, a class isn't really helpful here (unless it's here just to learn a bit about them). A function will suffice:

```
def access():
    room_code = 12534
    code = int(raw_input('Enter the code: '))
    if code == room_code:
        return 'good'
    return 'death'
```

Comment: I see, I guess I can try it that way as well. This code is actually part of a bigger game, hence the classes. Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary to store the keycodes:

```
code_dict = {'Boxing':'12345', 'Locker':'00000'}
```

and test

```
if code_input == code_dict['Boxing']:
    ...
```

Comment: Whoa, you just gave me a better idea for accessing the rooms in my game. I didn't even consider dicts, thanks1 :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Haidro's answer, but it seems to me you may want to allow more than one password?

If that is the case you would just need to do an 'IN' check.

For example.

```
def access():
    room_code = [12345,54321]
    code = int(raw_input('Enter the code: '))
    if code in room_code:
        return 'good'
    return 'death'
```